# Conditions When asp.net role provider redirects to login page

Tags: asp.net, role

It was perfectly working until i manually changed the role name in the database and also updated in the code file accordingly. I got the problem of redirecting to the login page. I've manually checked that the user is assigned to the given role and the spellings of rolename after modifications are also matched in both the db and the C# class.

I wanted to know what else could be the conditions of redirecting to the login page except that the user is explicitly not assigned to a particular role?

Comment: have you checked for that user is `authorized` or not.This is condition as well we may redirect user to login page if not `authorized`.

Comment: also check that your `rolename` in database having no some extra `whitespace`.

Comment: The user is authorized, because i too have the condition to redirect the user to some other error page.

Comment: Yes, I've checked the white spaces, the name in the database and in my code file is same, but the process never reached the page, where i've checked if the user has specific role or not.

Comment: I don't know much of the master page, but the sender object is assigned with login.aspx... I don't know from where does it assigned the sender object to login.aspx..

Comment: And to other pages, where the role provider is perfectly working, the sender object in site.master is the specific page that i want user to go.  I am using vs 2012, asp.net webform, and sql server 2008

Comment: use debugger and put your code as well

Comment: Till date i'm relying on the breakpoints and use the immediate window and Autos to debug the code. No any exception has been raised. In what step, the asp.net role provider validates itself that the user is not in role or their is some problem while reading rolename?

Comment: dear it's difficult to tell without code , only suggestion use `try catch` block.problem may be that the with the user u r assigning is not in any role something like that.

Comment: Thanks Rahul ji, for your time and support, I knew i had a minor problem, and I solved it, The problem was that i couldn't access the pages of the entire folder as it had a web.config file which blocks all the user and allow a single user though i had excluded it from the project. And after I deleted the config file from the folder, it worked instantly. This minor issue took my half day along.

Comment: Thank you! I was having this exact problem until now!